# Cycle with while on python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
dia_semana = int(input())
ndias = int(input())
dia_actual = 0
   while (ndias != 0):
     dia_actual = dia_semana + 1
     ndias -= 1
     if(dia_actual > 6):
       dia_actual = 0
print(dia_actual)
```

The purpose of this code is to read 2 variables (the first one being the starting point and the second one being the number I want to sum to the starting point (e.g. 3+4=7), but with a specific rule: it can only cycle through the numbers going from 0 to 6, and if it tries to go above 6 it will circle right back to 0. Whenever I run this code, instead of doing that, it gives me what it looks like random numbers (but it can be because we all know that the machine is never wrong). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give a few examples of desired input/output?

Comment: Try `dia_actual = (dia_semana + 1) % 7`. The modulus operator will ensure that `dia_actual` will wrap from 6 back to 0.

Comment: @ZacCrites But `dia_semana` never changes, so adding the modulo isn't going to change anything.

Comment: Then the code in your example is wrong. You yourself wrote `dia_actual = dia_semana + 1`

Comment: @ZacCrites No I didn't, I'm not the OP. ;)

Comment: Sorry I'm late, been AFK for a short while, what I intend to get from that piece of code is something like:  input: 3, 5 ; output: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dia_semana = int(input())
ndias = int(input())
dia_actual = dia_semana
while ndias != 0:
    dia_actual = (dia_actual + 1) % 7
    ndias -= 1
print(dia_actual)
```

Which will simplify to something like the following:

```
dia_semana = int(input())
ndias = int(input())
dia_actual = (dia_semana + ndias) % 7
print(dia_actual)
```